# How do I calculate solar irradiance of 1 m^2 flat square at a latitude and longitude?

Tags: gis, pvlib, solar

Is it possible using Python libraries like pysolar, pvlib or similarly to calculate the

- irradiance (Perez model) per day of the year
- of a 1 m^2 flat square
- situated at a certain latitude longitude

Comment: You can retrieve historical time series of irradiance from PVGIS using pvlib's get_pvgis_hourly function - you can even specify the tilt and azimuth angle directly using the function. Or do you have your own data?

Comment: @AdamJensen Which functions are you referring to? I'm pretty new to the library maybe you could post a short Python snippet as an answer. Would be awesome is it showed how to specify tilt and azimuth too - I didn't think that was possible.

Comment: May I ask if the question is related to your work with DroneDeploy (I've used DroneDeploy a number of times for stitching thermal orthomosaic maps fyi)?

Comment: Thanks @AdamJensen and yes it's something we are being asked about. Would be happy to chat if you're interested.

Comment: Welcome @nickponline. I've sent you a LinkedIn request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not already have irradiance data I would recommend either using data from [PVGIS](https://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/pvg_tools/en/tools.html) or [NREL's NSRDB](https://nsrdb.nrel.gov/) PSM3 (Americas).

In either case, I would suggest you first get familiar with the service through the web application. This should give you a good idea of the geographical coverage and the available parameters and settings.

Then, you can use the corresponding pvlib function to programmatically retrieve data. The function to retrieve PVGIS hourly data is: [pvlib.iotools.get_pvgis_hourly()](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/pvlib.iotools.get_pvgis_hourly.html).

A short example of how to retrieve irradiance data from PVGIS is shown below:

```
import pvlib
import pandas as pd

data, inputs, meta = pvlib.iotools.get_pvgis_hourly(
    latitude=55.7905, # North is positive
    longitude=12.5250, # East is positive
    start=pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'), # First available year is 2005
    end=pd.Timestamp('2020-12-31'), # Last available year is 2020 (depends on database)
    raddatabase='PVGIS-SARAH2',
    surface_tilt=5, # surface tilt angle
    surface_azimuth=0, # 0 degrees corresponds to south
    components=True, # Whether you want the individual components or just the total
    url='https://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/api/v5_2/', # URL for version 5.2
    )

data[['poa_direct','poa_sky_diffuse','poa_ground_diffuse']].plot(
    figsize=(6,4), subplots=True, sharex=True)
```

[image]